# Discard new branch changes

Tags: git

```
> git init
> touch a.txt
> git add a.txt
> git commit -m "a"
```

```
> git checkout -b feat-1
> mkdir NEW_DIR
> touch C.txt
```

realizes feat-1 branch won't be necessary
no adds or commits

How to remove feat-1 branch and all files and dirs created?
If I just checkout to main and `git branch -d feat-1` NEW_DIR and C.txt won't be removed.
So I have to add and commit everything (NEW_DIR and C.txt) on feat-1, checkout to main and them remove feat-1 branch.
Is there a better way to do it?
Thanks!

Comment: What's not to like about how you did it? Except you didn't have to commit the changes in the first place.

Comment: wont the changes still there if i do not commit them on feat-1 and remove the branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// main branch

git checkout -b feat-1

// make some changes
// realize changes are not needed anymore
```

At this point, when your changes have not yet been committed, you can throw out the changes with [`git-restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore). `git restore -W -S .` will delete your changes to both the Worktree (ie. the checked out files) and the Staging area (ie. any changes you've `git add`ed). I like to [alias](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases) this as `git clear`.

Then you can checkout another branch and delete the unnecessary branch.

```
git checkout main
git branch -d feat-1
```

`git branch -d` only works if the branch has no unmerged changes. If it does, use `-D`.

Comment: very helpful! `git restore -W -S` from the new branch, right? but would it work if i checkout to main first? thanks @schwern

Comment: Yes, assuming you can switch branches with uncommitted changes; there may be conflicts.